# Why Oauth2 does not work on server with tls 1.0 disable

Tags: oauth-2.0, tls1.2

I want to authenticate my application user with office 365 using Oauth v2, when I deploy my code on window server 2008 with TLS 1.2 enabled ,this give following error

```
The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.
```

but when we enable tls 1.0 then its start working properly?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that it's specifically the problem of oauth2.0.  Often older versions of Android don't support tls1.2 by default.  What sort of application is the client in this situation?

Comment: this is web application ,recently I move it to .net4.5